# Set position of comment-tooltip in xls-file using Apache POI

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I try to add a comment to a excel-field.

If I open the excel-file using Excel97 the Tooltip has bad boundings.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    HSSFWorkbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook();
    HSSFSheet sheet = workbook.createSheet();
    HSSFRow row = sheet.createRow(0);
    HSSFCell cell = row.createCell(0);
    cell.setCellValue("Test1");

    HSSFCreationHelper ch = sheet.getWorkbook().getCreationHelper();
    HSSFClientAnchor anchor = ch.createClientAnchor();
    HSSFComment comment = sheet.createDrawingPatriarch().createCellComment(anchor);
    comment.setRow(0);
    comment.setColumn(1);
    comment.setString(ch.createRichTextString("Test2"));
    comment.setAuthor("RM");
    cell.setCellComment(comment);
    sheet.autoSizeColumn(0);
    workbook.close();
    workbook.write(new FileOutputStream("d:/test.pdf"));
}
```

[image]

How to set the size of the tooltip programatically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add comment along the lines of the example in [Busy Developers' Guide to HSSF and XSSF Features](https://poi.apache.org/components/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#CellComments).

Using the `ClientAnchor` position settings (col1, dx1, row1, dy1, col2, dx2, row2, dy2)  you can set the position of the comment box.

Example:

```
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;

import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.util.Units;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook;

class CreateExcelWithComments {

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    String type = "HSSF";
    //String type = "XSSF";

    Workbook wb = ("HSSF".equals(type))?new HSSFWorkbook():new XSSFWorkbook();

    CreationHelper factory = wb.getCreationHelper();

    Sheet sheet = wb.createSheet();

    Row row   = sheet.createRow(0);
    Cell cell = row.createCell(0); // cell A1
    cell.setCellValue("A1");

    Drawing drawing = sheet.createDrawingPatriarch();

    // When the comment box is visible, have it show in a 1x3 space
    ClientAnchor anchor = factory.createClientAnchor();
    anchor.setCol1(cell.getColumnIndex()+1);                           // starts at column A + 1 = B
    anchor.setDx1(("HSSF".equals(type))?10*15:10*Units.EMU_PER_PIXEL); // plus 10 px     
    anchor.setCol2(cell.getColumnIndex()+2);                           // ends at column A + 2 = C
    anchor.setDx2(("HSSF".equals(type))?10*15:10*Units.EMU_PER_PIXEL); // plus 10 px    

    anchor.setRow1(row.getRowNum());                                   // starts at row 1
    anchor.setDy1(("HSSF".equals(type))?10*15:10*Units.EMU_PER_PIXEL); // plus 10 px
    anchor.setRow2(row.getRowNum()+3);                                 // ends at row 4
    anchor.setDy2(("HSSF".equals(type))?10*15:10*Units.EMU_PER_PIXEL); // plus 10 px


    // Create the comment and set the text+author
    Comment comment = drawing.createCellComment(anchor);
    RichTextString str = factory.createRichTextString("Hello, World!");
    comment.setString(str);
    comment.setAuthor("Apache POI");

    // Assign the comment to the cell
    cell.setCellComment(comment);

    String fname = ("HSSF".equals(type))?"./comment-xssf.xls":"./comment-xssf.xlsx";
    try (OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(fname)) {
        wb.write(out);
    }

    wb.close();

 }
}
```

Result:

[image]